# Creating/Retrieving a Cart programmatically

Tags: prestashop

For a module that I'm writing I need to retrieve a cart for a certain user (not necessary registered) after that a link is called and some data are passed.
My idea was to receive back a previously id passed that can help me to identify a certain cart.

My big problem is that I've search a lot for code cart creation into prestashop. Finally I've found something into

```
/* Cart already exists */
if ((int)$this->context->cookie->id_cart)
{
    $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
    if ($cart->OrderExists())
    {
        unset($this->context->cookie->id_cart, $cart, $this->context->cookie->checkedTOS);
        $this->context->cookie->check_cgv = false;
    }
    /* Delete product of cart, if user can't make an order from his country */
    elseif (intval(Configuration::get('PS_GEOLOCATION_ENABLED')) &&
            !in_array(strtoupper($this->context->cookie->iso_code_country), explode(';', Configuration::get('PS_ALLOWED_COUNTRIES'))) &&
            $cart->nbProducts() && intval(Configuration::get('PS_GEOLOCATION_NA_BEHAVIOR')) != -1 &&
            !FrontController::isInWhitelistForGeolocation() &&
            !in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], array('localhost', '127.0.0.1')))
        unset($this->context->cookie->id_cart, $cart);
    // update cart values
    elseif ($this->context->cookie->id_customer != $cart->id_customer || $this->context->cookie->id_lang != $cart->id_lang || $currency->id != $cart->id_currency)
    {
        if ($this->context->cookie->id_customer)
            $cart->id_customer = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_customer);
        $cart->id_lang = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_lang);
        $cart->id_currency = (int)$currency->id;
        $cart->update();
    }
    /* Select an address if not set */
    if (isset($cart) && (!isset($cart->id_address_delivery) || $cart->id_address_delivery == 0 ||
        !isset($cart->id_address_invoice) || $cart->id_address_invoice == 0) && $this->context->cookie->id_customer)
    {
        $to_update = false;
        if (!isset($cart->id_address_delivery) || $cart->id_address_delivery == 0)
        {
            $to_update = true;
            $cart->id_address_delivery = (int)Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId($cart->id_customer);
        }
        if (!isset($cart->id_address_invoice) || $cart->id_address_invoice == 0)
        {
            $to_update = true;
            $cart->id_address_invoice = (int)Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId($cart->id_customer);
        }
        if ($to_update)
            $cart->update();
    }
}

if (!isset($cart) || !$cart->id)
{
    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->id_lang = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_lang);
    $cart->id_currency = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_currency);
    $cart->id_guest = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_guest);
    $cart->id_shop_group = (int)$this->context->shop->id_shop_group;
    $cart->id_shop = $this->context->shop->id;
    if ($this->context->cookie->id_customer)
    {
        $cart->id_customer = (int)($this->context->cookie->id_customer);
        $cart->id_address_delivery = (int)(Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId($cart->id_customer));
        $cart->id_address_invoice = $cart->id_address_delivery;
    }
    else
    {
        $cart->id_address_delivery = 0;
        $cart->id_address_invoice = 0;
    }

    // Needed if the merchant want to give a free product to every visitors
    $this->context->cart = $cart;
    CartRule::autoAddToCart($this->context);
}
```

that is contained into `FrontController.php` (that seems to be called in every page). So, to me, a cart *should* always be present during a "user session".

But - yes, there's a but - when I try to retrieve a cart (in that way, into controller of my module)

```
$context=Context::getContext();
$id_cart=$context->cart->id;
```

`$id_cart` isn't there, so `cart` seems to miss. So I'm a little bit confused.

What's goin' on here? Someone could give me some pointers?

### PS.:

I've tried to replicate that function (only the `else` part) but it doesn't work

Comment: I ran some tests with your code pasted into a module hook. It returns the cart id as expected. The only situation when there is no cart id is when the cart is empty and the user isn't logged in, but I think this is normal behavior.

Comment: @yenshirak: yes, maybe it is the standard behaviour but I need to create a cart even when the user isn't logged in and a product isn't there. Maybe I should dig deeply into code where a cart is persisted to db and replicate that behaviour

Comment: http://www.psmodules.com/2017/10/25/prestashop-creating-cart-programmatically/

Comment: @All this psmodules link looks like spam, avoid clicking there's no information there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force cart generation when the user isn't logged in and there is no product in the cart:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
if (!$context->cart->id) {
  $context->cart->add();
  $context->cookie->id_cart = $context->cart->id;
}
$id_cart = $context->cart->id;
```

Take a look at the `processChangeProductInCart` method in `controllers/front/CartController.php`

Comment: Well, I was talking exactly about that, I was missing a small piece that I should've checked and I'm going to follow your suggestion and see if it works. Thank you for the moment, I'll let you know when I could try it ;-)

Comment: This gives an error in my case: `$context->cart` is null

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Prestashop 1.6, and @yenshiraks answer did not work for me. I cannot use `$context->cart->add();`, because `$context->cart`is null.

This is what worked in my case:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$cart_id = null
if($context->cookie->id_cart) {
    $cart = new Cart($context->cookie->id_cart);
    $cart_id = $cart->id; // just in case the cookie contains an invalid cart_id
}
if(empty($cart_id)) {
    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->id_lang = (int)$context->cookie->id_lang;
    $cart->id_currency = (int)$context->cookie->id_currency;
    $cart->id_guest = (int)$context->cookie->id_guest;
    $cart->id_shop_group = (int)$context->shop->id_shop_group;
    $cart->id_shop = $context->shop->id;
    $cart->add();
    $cart_id = $cart->id;
}
$context->cookie->id_cart = $cart_id;
```

To answer the question at the end: Even though a cart is always generated in the `FrontController`, it is not saved to the database, therefore the `id` is null.

If you are in a context, where the `FrontController` is instantiated (any page of the frontend, `$context->cart->add();` will suffice to save an empty cart to the database.

If on the other hand, you are in a script, that is called directly (like `prestashop/modules/my_module/script.php`), you have to use the above code.